# How to implement such a view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-adapterview

I got a trouble when i wanna to implement such view in my android app.

[image]

I thought two way to achieve this.

1. custom View and override onDraw() method. use Math.sin() to calculate the position of each item, then onLayout() method to layout them.
2. I think i can custom a  AdapterView, but it is too difficult for me.

Anyone can give me some suggestion? All comments is welcome. Thanks. :)

Comment: Go for the custom View with the onDraw override. Its by far your best option!

Comment: Search Google for `android radial menu`